# Docker compose mount volume by name and path

Tags: docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to setup Dev Containers within VS Code, and need a way to preserve extension, tools and settings after upgrading the container image (ex: from node-16 to node-18). Whenever the image needs to be upgraded, the container is deleted and a new one created, effectively resetting developers' custom configuration of the environment.

As far as I know, Docker creates an additional layer on top of the image layer for storing container specific data. I want to make that persistent, using a volume, if that makes any sense.

I have tried mounting / as the last mount, but I get the following error: `Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid specification: destination can't be '/'`.

My next, attempt is the following code:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    ...
    volumes:
      app_root/usr:/usr
      app_root/root:/root

volumes:
  app_root:
```

However, this doesn't work either, throwing the following error: `service "app" refers to undefined volume app_root/usr: invalid compose project`.

How do I create multiple mounts to different paths of the same volume, without creating a volume for each path?